# Is there any way to run "dir" directly?

Tags: delphi, shell

In [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499808/quickest-way-to-find-the-oldest-file-in-a-directory-using-delphi/2500173#2500173), where the asker needed a fast way to get a directory listing of a folder on a network drive, I suggested using the DOS "dir" command.  Unfortunately, it's a command, not a program, so you can't execute it with CreateProcess and so I had to put it in a batch file.  I don't really like that solution.  It feels like a hack to me.  Does anyone know a way to run dir from Delphi instead of from an external batch file?

Comment: How does using a batch file feel like a hack? It's pretty much the obvious solution.

Comment: Yeah, which is why I thought of it so quickly.  But "obvious solution" is not necessarily the same as "good solution".

Comment: It seems like you want something like a DOS API that will take in commands and return the results for you to display within any textbox in your app or something, right ?

Comment: There's nothing bad about using a batch file as a solution to this problem. It's one of the general purposes of a batch file. Is there a particular reason you don't want to use a batch? It's not like doing so will add extra hangtime to your app.

Answer (score 17):

Invisible Solution (Create a pipe, execute the command, redirect stdout to the pipe, read out the pipe):

```
function Console(const Command: String): String; 
var 
  StartupInfo: TStartupInfo; 
  ProcessInfo: TProcessInformation; 
  SecurityAttr: TSecurityAttributes; 
  OutputPipeRead, OutputPipeWrite: THandle; 
  Res: Boolean; 
  BufSize: Cardinal; 
  Buffer: String; 
  BytesRead: Cardinal; 
begin 
  FillChar(ProcessInfo, SizeOf(TProcessInformation), 0); 

  FillChar(SecurityAttr, SizeOf(TSecurityAttributes), 0); 
  SecurityAttr.nLength := SizeOf(SecurityAttr); 
  SecurityAttr.bInheritHandle := true; 
  SecurityAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor := nil; 

  CreatePipe(OutputPipeRead, OutputPipeWrite, @SecurityAttr, 0); 

  FillChar(StartupInfo, SizeOf(TStartupInfo), 0); 
  StartupInfo.cb:=SizeOf(StartupInfo); 
  StartupInfo.hStdInput := 0; 
  StartupInfo.hStdOutput := OutputPipeWrite; 
  StartupInfo.hStdError := OutputPipeWrite; 
  StartupInfo.wShowWindow := SW_HIDE; 
  StartupInfo.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW or STARTF_USESTDHANDLES; 

  Res := CreateProcess(nil, PChar(command), nil, nil, true, 
                   CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE or CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE or 
                   NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil, nil, StartupInfo, ProcessInfo); 

  CloseHandle(OutputPipeWrite); 

  Result := ''; 

  if Res then 
  begin  
    SetLength(Buffer, 5000); 
    BufSize := Length(Buffer); 
    repeat 
      Res := ReadFile(OutputPipeRead, Buffer[1], BufSize, BytesRead, nil); 
      Result := Result + Copy(Buffer, 1, BytesRead); 
    until not Res; 

    WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInfo.hProcess, INFINITE); 
    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess); 
  end; 

  CloseHandle(OutputPipeRead); 
end;
```

Sample Usage:

```
ShowMessage(Console('cmd /c dir C:\'));
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a batch file, you can just execute:

```
cmd.exe /c dir
```

You can check the option to command with `cmd /?`:

```
c:> cmd /?
CMD [/A | /U] [/Q] [/D] [/E:ON | /E:OFF] [/F:ON | /F:OFF] [/V:ON | /V:OFF]
    [[/S] [/C | /K] string]

/C  Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
: : : : :
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it invisibly? Calling cmd.exe will open up a DOS window in the middle of your app.

Comment: @Mason: See Mef's answer. The trick is to set wShowWIndow to SW_HIDE and include STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW in dwFlags.

Answer (score 3):

Why not [`FindFirstFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28VS.85%29.aspx)? It returns an attribute for each item that you can compare with `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` to check for a directory. I highly suspect that `dir` doesn't do anything else.
Using the `dir` command is like using a bar to type on the keyboard.

Comment: Having followed the other thread, I think the OP was more interested in the invocation of the command shell interpreter, rather than "dir" specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Using [DSiWin32](http://17slon.com/gp/gp/dsiwin32.htm):

```
sl := TStringList.Create;
if DSiExecuteAndCapture('cmd.exe /c dir', sl, 'c:\test', exitCode) = 0 then
  // exec error
else
  // use sl
sl.Free;
```